# Tensorflow: has no attribute 'load_labelmap'

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I followed the steps described on their Github to install the [Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md) and then I ran this script:

```
python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
```

and the test were successful, so I assumed everything was setup correctly. Next I tried to run the Jupyter Notebook with qtconsole to detect objects in the test images. However it returns this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-be6fe1ba8733> in <module>()
----> 1 from utils import label_map_util
      2 
      3 from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
      4 

~\Desktop\Objectdetection\models-master\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py in <module>()
     20 import tensorflow as tf
     21 from google.protobuf import text_format
---> 22 from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
     23 
     24 

~\Desktop\Objectdetection\models-master\object_detection\object_detection.py in <module>()
    114 
    115 
--> 116 label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
    117 categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
    118 category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

AttributeError: module 'utils.label_map_util' has no attribute 'load_labelmap'
```

Does anyone have an idea what the cause of this problem is?

Thanks.

Comment: That traceback describes "`ipython-input-3`" and yet you show a command-line invocation of `python`.  Can you show the error that you get with the command-line invocation instead?  If you can't reproduce it, then it's almost certainly related to the problem.  IIRC `ipython` doesn't play nice with virtualenv (unless you build/install it in your virtualenv?)

Comment: So I converted the Jupyter Notebook object_detection_tutorial.ipynb to a python script and invoked it with ipython from the command-line. I still get the same error.

Comment: The [commit that added this feature is relatively new](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/commit/a4944a57ad2811e1f6a7a87589a9fc8a776e8d3c).  Are you sure you got a compatible release?

Comment: I downloaded the repository just 3 days ago, quite a while after the commit you linked. Anyway, I just cloned it again and run the Jupyter notebook and it seems to work now! Not sure what exactly the problem was, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the file `~\Desktop\Objectdetection\models-master\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py`

Try changing this:

`from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2`

to this:

`from protos import string_int_label_map_pb2`

**Explanation**:

The function `load_labelmap` in the module `label_map_util` isn't accessible because the import of `string_int_label_map_pb2` is failing.

You can see this if you look at the output of `print(dir(label_map_util))`.

When using `object_detection.protos`:

`['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'logging', 'text_format', 'tf']`

After the changing the relative path to `protos` the function should be accessible:

`['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_validate_label_map', 'convert_label_map_to_categories', 'create_category_index', 'get_label_map_dict', 'load_labelmap', 'logging', 'string_int_label_map_pb2', 'text_format', 'tf']`