# from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2 ModuleNotFoundError:

Tags: python, tensorflow, protoc

I'm using the offical code from tensorflow in python from github, but I dont get passed that error:

```
import tensorflow as tf

import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append("..")



# ## Object detection imports
# Here are the imports from the object detection module.

# In[3]:
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
 File "C:/Users/azach/Desktop/python/tensorflow/models- 
master/research/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py", line 22, in 
<module>
from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'
```

As someone suggested here:

[Tensorflow: has no attribute 'load_labelmap'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45313687/tensorflow-has-no-attribute-load-labelmap)

I changed

```
 from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
```

to this:

```
 from protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
```

I'm using Python 3.6.5, tensorflow 1.8 on windows 10. The *.proto Files were compiled with protoc 3.4.

Edit: Error from cmd:

```
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'label_map_util' is not defined
>>> categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, 
max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'label_map_util' is not defined
>>> category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'label_map_util' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows OS, From the command prompt change directory to research(parent of object_detection) Folder run the following. Change the commands accordingly based on the OS you are on

1) protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

2) SET PYTHONPATH=%cd%;%cd%\slim

Then launch the notebook from same command line and try to run.

I am not sure purpose of the following line, try running without line
sys.path.append("..")